# How to share object records to customer community users?

Tags: apex, customer-portal, customer-community, apex-sharing

I have a requirement to share a custom object records to customer community users. The opportunity object has Event Booking and contact roles as related list.

**Eg:** There is an opportunity called **`Test opp`** and it has 3 contact roles such as: **`Role1`**, **`Role2`** and **`Role3`**. Out of this 3 contact roles, a particular contact is customer community enabled user. So when I insert a event booking record, this record should be shared to that contact role.

Only the event booking record related to that opportunity only need to be shared to the contact role when logged in as customer community user. I searched for this in google and found that apex sharing rule is not available for customer community user.

Is there any alternative solution? What can be the workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

If your sharing requirements cannot be met via customer community licence then you will need to move to customer community plus licenses.These have ability to share records via apex or sharing rule and ability to set up role hierarchy

Comment: @ Mohith srivastava.. But in several forums I found that "Customer Communities users do not have access to the full sharing model and therefore can't be added on a __Share record. The only way to share a record with a Customer Communities user is through Sharing Sets and Sharing Groups."

Comment: Ah right. I updated my ans and confirmed with SFDC product team that you need customer community plus license

Comment: With Customer community plus license, can we write apex sharing for the Event booking object.? And will it work?

Comment: Yes it will work :)